# Adding to vector of objects with attributes determined by constantly changing values

Tags: arrays, dynamic, audio, vector, openframeworks

For this issue, I have done research, but I am not sure I have been searching for the right terms? Maybe someone can help...

I am writing an app in openframeworks that is basically a sound visualizer. What I am trying to do is have the program create and draw a rectangle at a certain point, the height of which is determined by the frequency of audio input at the moment of the rectangle's creation. Then, I want the program to draw another rectangle next to it, the height of which determined by the frequency at THAT moment, so forth and so on. (I am also planning to pan this to the left every time, so that it is creating a very long chain of rectangles).
The rectangles are going to look like buildings (drawing a city scape as it goes), so I have created a class of them with very simple attributes: position, height, etc. and the main work (correct me if I am wrong) is going to be in the main part of the application.
The problems I have been having are in the drawing of the object and then having its height correspond to a frequency. Also, I don't want the height of the rectangle to change once it is created, so I am having trouble getting that to happen correctly. Right now, I have only managed to create a single large rectangle that flickers up and down with the sound input. 
I am not entirely sure how I should be adding to the vector an object with the correct attributes each second and having that instance of the object's property stay static. 
I am not sure if I am asking the right questions correctly, but maybe someone can help?

Here is the top level of the app code:

```
#include "testApp.h"

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::setup(){

    ofSetFrameRate(60);
    ofBackground(0,30,60);

    //sound stream setup and such
    ofSoundStreamSetup(0,2,this, 44100, BUFFER_SIZE, 4);
    left = new float[BUFFER_SIZE];
    right = new float[BUFFER_SIZE];

    FFTanalyzer.setup(44100, BUFFER_SIZE/2, 1);
    FFTanalyzer.peakHoldTime = 15; // hold longer
    FFTanalyzer.peakDecayRate = 0.95f; // decay slower
    FFTanalyzer.linearEQIntercept = 0.9f; // reduced gain at lowest frequency
    FFTanalyzer.linearEQSlope = 0.01f; // increasing gain at higher frequencies
    numOctaves=1;


    //control panel setup
    panel.setup("control", 770, 0, 300, 150);
    panel.addPanel("fft settings", 1, false);
    panel.setWhichPanel("fft settings");
    panel.addSlider("Number of Sub Octaves","NUM_OCT",  1, 1,12, false);

    //set up buildings
    for (int i = 0; i <  bldgs.size() ; i+= 20){

    }

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::update(){
    panel.update();
    if(numOctaves != panel.getValueI("NUM_OCT")){
        numOctaves = panel.getValueI("NUM_OCT");
        panel.setValueI("NUM_OCT", numOctaves,0);
        FFTanalyzer.setup(44100, BUFFER_SIZE/2, numOctaves);
    }



}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::draw(){

    panel.draw();
    static int index=0;
    float avg_power = 0.0f;

    /* do the FFT   */
    myfft.powerSpectrum(0,(int)BUFFER_SIZE/2, left,BUFFER_SIZE,&magnitude[0],&phase[0],&power[0],&avg_power);


    for (int i = 0; i < (int)(BUFFER_SIZE/2); i++){
        freq[i] = magnitude[i];
    }
    FFTanalyzer.calculate(freq);
    float binDrawWidth = (ofGetWidth()-20)/FFTanalyzer.nAverages;



//float bldgHeighTemp;
for (int i = 0; i <  1000 ; i+=30){
    for (int f = 0; f < (int)(BUFFER_SIZE/2); f++){
        bldg temp;

        freqs[i] = freq[f]*-6;
        temp.bldgPosX = i;
        temp.bldgPosY = ofGetHeight()/2;
        temp.bldgWidth = 30;
        temp.bldgHeight = freqs[i];
        temp.draw();

        bldgs.push_back(temp);
    }
}






}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::keyPressed(int key){

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::keyReleased(int key){

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::mouseMoved(int x, int y ){

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::mouseDragged(int x, int y, int button){
    panel.mouseDragged(x,y,button);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::mousePressed(int x, int y, int button){
    panel.mousePressed(x,y,button);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::mouseReleased(int x, int y, int button){
    panel.mouseReleased();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::windowResized(int w, int h){

}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::audioReceived     (float * input, int bufferSize, int nChannels){
    // samples are "interleaved"
    for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++){
        left[i] = input[i*2];
        right[i] = input[i*2+1];
    }
}
```

[edit] testapp.h

```
#ifndef _TEST_APP
#define _TEST_APP


#include "ofMain.h"
#include "fft.h"
#include "FFTOctaveAnalyzer.h"
#include "ofxControlPanel.h"
#include "bldg.h"

#define BUFFER_SIZE 512

class testApp : public ofBaseApp{

    public:
        void setup();
        void update();
        void draw();

        void keyPressed  (int key);
        void keyReleased(int key);
        void mouseMoved(int x, int y );
        void mouseDragged(int x, int y, int button);
        void mousePressed(int x, int y, int button);
        void mouseReleased(int x, int y, int button);
        void windowResized(int w, int h);

        void audioReceived  (float * input, int bufferSize, int nChannels);

        ofxControlPanel  panel;
        int numOctaves;


        FFTOctaveAnalyzer FFTanalyzer;

        float * left;
        float * right;
        int     bufferCounter;
        fft     myfft;

        float magnitude[BUFFER_SIZE];
        float phase[BUFFER_SIZE];
        float power[BUFFER_SIZE];
        float freq[BUFFER_SIZE/2];

        vector <float> freqs;
        vector <bldg> bldgs;
};

#endif
```

what isn't working is that it isn't creating single instances of the object and/or each instance's attributes are constantly changing according to frequency, which isn't the behavior I'm trying to achieve; what I want is for each object to be created at a certain height and stay that way, then a new ones created next to it so forth  and so on, like every second or so.

Make any sense? I am still trying to figure out how to ask the right questions.
Thanks,
Bree

Comment: please edit your post and add your testApp.h file. And can you say exactly what is not working right now in your app?

Comment: added them above Ben, think you can help? Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok as far as I understand your problem you need to do this, maybe this helps:

Try to store pointers in your `bldgs` vector

```
vector<bldg*> bldgs;
```

and add new objects to it with

```
    bldg* temp;

    freqs[i] = freq[f]*-6;
    temp->bldgPosX = i;
    temp->bldgPosY = ofGetHeight()/2;
    temp->bldgWidth = 30;
    temp->bldgHeight = freqs[i];

    bldgs.push_back(temp);
```

remove the draw method from here and draw every `bldg` on every frame. add this to your draw method:

```
for(int i = 0; i < bldgs.size(); i++)
{
    bldgs[i]->draw();
}
```

it would be a better practise to move everything not directly related to draw to put in the update method of your testApp. so for example move your creation and filling the vector stuff to the update method.

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks for the help. It makes sense, but it seems to be constantly crashing...

I tried limiting the number of object instances to 100, but it continues to crash. Any ideas?

Thanks!!!!!!!!

Comment: When it executes the code.... when it tries to load the sketch window, it crashes >.<

Comment: maybe I need to start over... I can't even get these thigns to appear now >.<

Comment: maybe the error is somewhere else not related to the vector. try to debug your app with your IDE